# How to use Material colours in react styled components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, styled-components

Is it possible to use the Material UI colours in react styled components? If so, what is the syntax for it?

I'm trying as follows:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import indigo from '@material-ui/core/colors/indigo';

export const Icons = styled.span`

    color: {  indigo['A400'] };
`
;
```

I also tried (all guesses):

```
color: blue[500]
color: { blue[500] }
color: "blue[500]"
```

I can't find a way that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inside a template literal so use `${}` syntax if you opt to evaluate JavaScript expressions

```
export const Icons = styled.span`
  color: ${indigo['A400']};
`;
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: You are welcome. Here is `styled-components`' docs behind their implementation of Tagged Template Literals: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#tagged-template-literals